# Django validate_unique method already exists message

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Thinking How to get the instance pk that exists during `validate_unique`?
it is not a good practice to overwrite the method validate_unique and I don't know if it would be correct to validate unique fields in the `clean()` method.

but imagine the following situation:
you want to show admin users which is the instance that already exists so they can edit it if they want, I think it would be more intuitive when working with thousands of data.

> the following code is just an example - think about  it as a pseudocode
>   although I tried it and it works, I know it could be better

```
    def clean(self):
        lockup ={}

        unique_togethers = self._meta.unique_together[0]#these could throw an error

        for field in unique_togethers:
            f = self._meta.get_field(field)

            value = getattr(self, f.attname)

            if value is None:
                 continue

            if f.primary_key and not self._state.adding:
                    continue

            lockup[str(field)] = value

        qs = snippet.objects.filter(**lockup)

        if qs.exists and self._state.adding:
            raise ValidationError(
                     format_html('''this object all ready exist plese edit it on <a href="{}">Edit</a>''', 
                                  reverse('admin:testing_snippet_change', args=(qs[0].pk,))))
```

Is this approach correct, how to apply it to the validation_unique method to works in all unique validations?

**Result**
[image: validation message on django admin]

[image: validation message on django modelform]

Comment: Django normally already validates `unique_together` constraints in the form. It is not clear to me why you want to implement the same logic?

Comment: yes, I know that, but How to show admin users which is the instance that already exists so they can edit it if they want?

Comment: Django tries to enforce this at the database level as well. Most databases support this. So even if the form does not rejects it, the database will likely do that.

Comment: I'm not overwriting anything, I just want to show admin users that object x already exists inside database records and show them the link where to edit it. if you have 100k records or more, that might help, don't you think?